# MySQL Won't Start After Update

Tags: mysql, systemd

I just finished that Debian upgrade to Stretch, and as a result, we had an issue with our mailserver (postfix/courier/saslauthd/mysql - nothing was authenticating). As a result, I did the forbidden, and rebooted the server. Now, I can't get MySQL to come back up. The systemd error is irritatingly vague and not much to search based on. This is all I've got:

```
$ sudo service mysql status
● mysql.service - LSB: Start and stop the mysql database server daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/mysql; generated; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2017-08-29 19:13:26 UTC; 2min 49s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 18202 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/mysql stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 19651 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/mysql start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Aug 29 19:12:55 server.name.tld systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Start and stop the mysql database server daemon...
Aug 29 19:12:55 server.name.tld su[19677]: Successful su for mysql by root
Aug 29 19:12:55 server.name.tld su[19677]: + ??? root:mysql
Aug 29 19:12:55 server.name.tld su[19677]: pam_unix(su:session): session opened for user mysql by (uid=0)
Aug 29 19:13:26 server.name.tld /etc/init.d/mysql[19977]: 0 processes alive and '/usr/bin/mysqladmin --defaults-file=/etc/mysql/debian.cnf ping' resulted in
Aug 29 19:13:26 server.name.tld mysql[19651]: Starting MySQL database server: mysqld . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . failed!
Aug 29 19:13:26 server.name.tld systemd[1]: mysql.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Aug 29 19:13:26 server.name.tld systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Start and stop the mysql database server daemon.
Aug 29 19:13:26 server.name.tld systemd[1]: mysql.service: Unit entered failed state.
Aug 29 19:13:26 server.name.tld systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

The only addition syslog has on top of that is mysqladmin not being able to connect to the socket. Which is just because MySQL isn't actually starting in the first place.

I've checked to make sure it can write to /var/run/mysqld, as well as the appropriate logging directories. The MySQ: logs aren't actually of any help; nothing has been written to any of them since the shutdown messages when I rebooted. I've also double checked that directory entries in /etc/mysql/my.cnf are all where they're supposed to be. I've also had myisam-recover-options and key_buffer_size variable names updated from the old version.

I can start mysql manually with `sudo mysqld`, the process will run and the socket file will show in the correct place, but nothing actually *happens*. All I get in the console is:

```
2017-08-29 19:35:03 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2017-08-29 19:35:03 0 [Warning] Insecure configuration for --secure-file-priv: Data directory is accessible through --secure-file-priv. Consider choosing a different directory.
2017-08-29 19:35:03 0 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 5.6.36-1~dotdeb+7.1-log) starting as process 24760 ...
```

Pre-edit: *Eventually* (like 5+mins) it gets back to the command prompt with MySQL running, but it doesn't seem to *stay* running. After a while, I'll come back to find it just... stopped. MySQL logs still show nothing, can't find anything in syslog about it. I gave up, backed up the DBs and reinstalled MySQL (just the actual server package, not -common, as it was gonna remove a bunch of packages I didn't wanna risk). After reinstalling... it did exactly the same as before.

Unfortunately, even when MySQL is temporarily running, saslauthd still won't auth against the DB for postfix/courier (which it did fine before). I guess that's for another post once I get MySQL running properly again.

I'm kinda at the end of my wits at the end of a very long day.

Edit: Solution in comments: [MySQL Won't Start After Update](https://serverfault.com/questions/871241/mysql-wont-start-after-update#comment1121958_871375)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The version of MySQL in Debian 8 "Jessie" is 5.5. When installing, most users will install the mysql-server package, which depends on the mysql-server-5.5 package. In Debian 9 "Stretch" the mysql-server package depends on a new package called default-mysql-server. This package in turn depends on mariadb-server-10.1. There is no default-mysql-server package in Jessie.

Read  article of upgrade `mysql` to `mariadb` at [Moving from MySQL to MariaDB in Debian 9](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/the-mariadb-library/moving-from-mysql-to-mariadb-in-debian-9/)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried that, had to manually recreate /var/lib/mysql first (for testing I gave it mysql:root 770) as prior to that, it complained that the partition was too full (it most definitely is not, single partition for the actual filesystem, 17% usage). However, once I recreated /var/lib/mysql, it returned to the exact same error.

However, MySQL will now no longer even run manually in the console with `mysqld`. It gives the same text as in my OP, but exits immediately.

Comment: So, progress. The mysql user had been disabled during the upgrade it seems (no shell). Sorting that lets me `su mysql` and run `/usr/sbin/mysqld`. I get some logging finally! (Linked logs because of char limit) Running it using the *original* /var/lib/mysql gets me this: https://brutix.com/img/old-mysql.txt - and running it with the blank /var/lib/mysql gets me this: https://brutix.com/img/blank-mysql.txt - Running the blank a *second* time gets me this: https://brutix.com/img/blank-mysql2.txt - Running `mysql_upgrade` as it asks gets me this: https://brutix.com/img/mysql_upgrade.txt

Comment: You not need to recreate mysql data directory. Simply delete it. MySQL server will create this directory with right permissions after its service will be started.

Comment: Hi, quote from above: "had to manually recreate /var/lib/mysql first as prior to that, it complained that the partition was too full (it most definitely is not, single partition for the actual filesystem, 17% usage)" systemd would still not start it without me first creating the directory. Running mysqld as `su mysql` causes it to give the same console feedback as the OP, but it then exits immediately with "[ERROR] Aborting". /var/lib itself is only writeable by root.

Comment: Do you really have backup by `mysqldump`?

Comment: I'm sorry. I understand your problem. It is happened because Debian 9 hasn't got MySQL in its repository.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked to see if all the folders/files (that are needed by mySQL to run) are set to the right owner:group and permissions?

Comment: Sorry, just to confirm, yes I've been over and double checked that. I've managed to get some logging, which I've posted below Mikhail Khirgiy's response.